# How to find the origin of a browser event

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, events, google-chrome-devtools

My web application started firing off a ton of events while idle and I've been trying to hunt down who has been firing them.

I received a Chrome performance profile from a client and discovered that the events are being fired from the root of execution. This makes me believe that the events are coming from the user. But the odd thing is, is that the events are being fired so quickly that it's impossible for a user to perform them.

I also doubt that these are being executed through the script or a timer because then the stack trace would be prepended with a timer fired or another function.

So now I'm at square one where I have reasons to doubt that a script is firing them and I have reasons to doubt that a user is firing them.

I'm going to reach out to my client and `monitorEvents` (https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/events) on the element and then check to see if the event being fired `isTrusted` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/isTrusted). If it is Trusted, then I have no idea what could be happening external to Chrome that's causing so many events. And if it isn't Trusted then I have no idea how to track the code that's firing so many events.

[Zoomed in profile execution stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Aq1gi.png)

[Zoomed out profile execution stack](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbktY.png)

Comment: Got done talking with the client. The event was trusted. All jquery keydown event information about which key was pressed was all undefined (char, charCode, ctrlkey, key, keyCode, shiftKey, which...). The events were being triggered by Chrome's password manager. It was frequently autofilling the username and password field (several times a second). I don't know why it was doing this, but it seems like a Chrome bug.

Comment: So the original bug was a chrome bug on v63. Password manager was focusing, autofilling, then blurring out of a hidden input. I guess this means, if there isn't a stack before the triggering of an event, its going to be a trusted event that's fired by either the browser itself or the user.